# check array order(ascending) using hint of merge sort

Tags: recursion

**question:**
Write a recursive method flgIsSorted to check if a given array (provided as a parameter) is sorted in increasing order. The method returns true if and only if the array is sorted in increasing order. Hint, when the array has only one element, it is sorted. If the first half is sorted, the second half is sorted, and the first element of the second half is not smaller than the last element in the first half, the array is sorted. Your initial method can only take one parameter – the array. That method can call another auxiliary method that takes other parameters.

```
public boolean flgIsSorted(int a[], int startIndex, int endIndex ){
    boolean result = false;
    if(startIndex < endIndex){
        int mid = (startIndex + endIndex)/2;
        flgIsSorted(a, startIndex, mid);
        flgIsSorted(a, mid+1, endIndex);
        result = check(a, startIndex, mid, endIndex);
    }
    return result;
}

public boolean check(int a[], int startIndex, int mid, int endIndex){

    //deal with left array
    //If array has odd number of elements, 
    //left array will be even number
    //and right array will be odd number
    int n1 = mid - startIndex + 1;

    // n1 is index, and we need n1 + 1 spots for copy array
    int L[] = new int[n1 + 1];

    //copy subarray A[p..q] into L[0..n1], 
    //i starts from the beginning of unsorted array
    for(int i = startIndex; i <= mid + 1; i++){
        //make sure copy to the index 0 of left array
        L[i - startIndex] = a[i];
    }
    L[n1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    //deal with right array
    int n2 = endIndex - mid;
    int R[] = new int[n2 + 1];

    //copy subarray A[q+1..r] into R[0..n2]
    for(int j = mid + 1; j <=  endIndex; j++){
        //make sure start from the index 0 of right array
        R[j - (mid + 1)] = a[j];
    }
    R[n2] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;  
    boolean result = false;
    for(int k = startIndex; k <= endIndex; k++){
        if(L[i] < R[j]){
            //a[k] = L[i];
            i++;
            result = true;
            System.out.println("true in check");
        }else{
            //a[k] = R[j];
            j++;
            System.out.println("false in check");
            result = false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("return in check final");
    return result;
}
```

**Problem:**
It always returns true.

Comment: Add a tag for the programming language you're using. It looks like it might be C#, or am I guessing wrong? (Yup, I guessed wrong, C# wouldn't have `boolean` - so is it Java?)

Answer (score 0):

I think I just figured it out this morning. At least the output is what I want now.

Code:

```
    public boolean flgIsSorted(int a[], int startIndex, int endIndex){
    boolean result = false;
    if(a.length == 1){
        result = true;
    }else{
        if(startIndex < endIndex){
            int mid = (startIndex + endIndex)/2;
            if(a[startIndex] <= a[mid + 1]){
                result = true;
            }else{
                result = false;
            }
            flgIsSorted(a, startIndex, mid);
            flgIsSorted(a, mid + 1, endIndex);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```